# How to get some parameter in the child class through the base class

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, swift3

I'm stuck.
I try to make right code's architect but I can not solve following case:
I have some base class and inherited from it class like:

```
class BaseClass {
   var name: String
   init(name: String) {
      self.name = name
   }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
   var otherName: String
   init(otherName: String) {
      self.otherName = otherName
   }
}
```

And the following function:

```
func someFunc() -> BaseClass {
   let a = ChildClass.init(otherName: "NAME")
   return a
}
```

How can I get the parameter "otherName"?
The available parameter is only one - "name", but I want to get "otherName":

```
let b = someFunc()
b.PARAMETERS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
(b as! ChildClass).otherName
```

Your function returns your object as `BaseClass` object, so you can't access any of `ChildClass` methods. In order to access `ChildClass` methods, you need to cast your object to `ChildClass` using `as!`, as we know it is a `ChildClass` object. After that you'll be able to access all the parameters of `ChildClass`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about it